# Prepare data for JS renderer

Tags: code-golf

It's asked to write a script to generate a source data to feed a JavaScript renderer.

### JS Renderer documentation

The JS renderer is this script:

```js
function o(x){
  r=x.split(' ');
  (d=document).write('<style>i{position:absolute;width:10;height:10;background:#000}</style>');
  for(i=0;i<r.length;++i){c=r[i].split(',');d.write('<i style=top:'+(e=eval)(c[0])+';left:'+e(c[1])+'></i>')
  }
}
```

It takes as input a list of X/Y coordinates separated by spaces and commas and prints on DOM the points as **10×10** pixel squares.

For example, if you call the script with:

```js
o('0,0 10,0 20,0 30,0 40,0 20,10 20,20 0,30 10,30 20,30 30,30 40,30 0,50 10,50 20,50 30,50 40,50');
```

It will print:

[image: HI example]

Notice that the values can be expressed as calculations, so it will accept:

```js
o('10*2,50/5');
```

### Your task

Write a script that, given as input a string of characters (`[A-Z0-9 ]`; uppercase letters, numbers, spaces) prints on **`stdout`** the coordinates to feed the JS renderer.

#### Rules

- The "line-height" of the characters should be of at least 50px
- Your script doesn't need to run the JS parser
- The expected output format is: `x,y x,y x,y x,y`
- The shortest code wins

**Bonus**: if you could reduce the length of the JS renderer without changing the behavior would be great **:)**

Comment: Do the letters have to be all uppercase? or just readable?

Comment: all uppercase, I've made it clearer in the description.

Comment: Your rules say expected output is `x,y` but your code produces `'top:'+eval(cp[0])+';left:'+eval(cp[1])` which is the opposite. Which one is right?

Comment: Unhandled Error: Security error: attempted to read protected variable: i --> result of running your code on opera 12.16 on windows 8 pro 64bits.

Comment: Sorry but your code is a "disaster" in terms of performance and good practices in Javascript. Besides, it throws an exception on opera 12.16. Here is an improved (and longer) version: `function o(x){
 (d=document).head.innerHTML='<style>i{position:absolute;width:10;height:10;background:#000}</style>';
 for(var i=0,r=x.split(' '),l=r.length,e=eval,c;i<l;++i)
 {
  c=r[i].split(',');d.body.innerHTML+=('<i style=top:'+e(c[0])+';left:'+e(c[1])+'></i>');
 }
}`. This reduces the performance hits and gets rid of the `document.write` and the exception, maintaining a perfect DOM tree.

Comment: It's a golfed code, it's normal that it throws warnings :)  Tobia: x and y are just conventions, just follow the examples

Comment: Removed 23 chars: `function o(x){r=x.split(' ');(d=document).write('<style>i{position:absolute;width:9;height:9;background:red}</style>');for(i=0;i<r.length;++i){c=r[i].split(',');d.write('<i style=top:'+(e=eval)(c[0])+';left:'+e(c[1])+'></i>')}}`

Comment: Is html+javascript out not having a stdout?

Comment: @edc65 generally `alert/prompt` are accepted for JS STDIN/STDOUT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mathematica - 164 bytes

I'm happy to agree if you call this cheating, but it wasn't ruled out in the question. I let Mathematica rasterise the string and then throw away all white pixels and generate instructions from the rest:

```
 g=""<>MapIndexed[If[#<1,"",{h,w}=ToString/@(10#2);h<>","<>w<>""]&,ImageData@Rasterize[#,RasterSize->(n=5StringLength@#),ImageSize->n]/.{(1.)..}->0/.{_,_,_}->1,{2}]&
```

It could probably be golfed down even further. Especially the `/.{(1.)..}->0/.{_,_,_}->1` looks suspiciously like it could be simplified.

Slightly ungolfed:

```
g[str_] := (
    n = 5*StringLength[str];
    pixels = ImageData[Rasterize[str, RasterSize->n, ImageSize->n]]
                /. {1., 1., 1.} -> 0 
                /. {_, _, _} -> 1;
    StringJoin[
      MapIndexed[
        If[#1 < 1,
           "",
           {h, w} = Map[ToString, 10*#2];
           h <> "," <> w <> ""
        ] &,
        pixels,
        {2}
      ]
    ]
);
```

This will handle really any characters in the string, and you can tweak the size by adjusting the `5` (which means letters are 5 pixels wide, which meets your requirement of them being 50 actual pixels tall).

Here is some example output using a resolution of `7`:

[image]

And here using a resolutiong of `9`:

[image]

And `12`:

[image]

(The screenshots are somewhat minified to fit SE's column width, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 196 chars

```
f←37 5 3⍴(555/2)⊤95x⊥32-⍨⎕UCS'ne,[9fkO!|UUmYb~qu"*5n2wJgBe1P~P+E)$?ZGHb4{W(:edC2JdpirhX4I@m/K/q,ww <=:N%(euf9AJ"'
⎕←1↓∊{⍕¨' '⍺','⍵}/¨↑,/{10×(2↑4×⍵-1)∘+¨1-⍨a/⍥,⍳⍴a←⍉f[(' ',⎕A,∊⍕¨0,⍳9)⍳⍵⌷s;;]}¨⍳⍴s←⍞
```

Dialect is [Nars2000](http://www.nars2000.org/).

The first line produces the font, which I took from [this page](http://robey.lag.net/2010/01/23/tiny-monospace-font.html). I've encoded it in base 95 as printable ASCII characters, so the first line decodes it and turns it into a 37×5×3 bitmap.

The second line reads a line of input. For each character it extracts the right bitmap from the font, produces a list of coordinates of the 'on' bits, adds an offset to the first coordinate (x) depending on the position in the string, multiplies by 10, formats the result as required, and outputs it.

Here is the output for `HELLO WORLD 9`

```
0,0 0,10 0,20 0,30 0,40 10,20 20,0 20,10 20,20 20,30 20,40 40,0 40,10 40,20 40,30 40,40 50,0 50,20 50,40 60,0 60,20 60,40 80,0 80,10 80,20 80,30 80,40 90,40 100,40 120,0 120,10 120,20 120,30 120,40 130,40 140,40 160,10 160,20 160,30 170,0 170,40 180,10 180,20 180,30 240,0 240,10 240,20 240,30 240,40 250,30 260,0 260,10 260,20 260,30 260,40 280,10 280,20 280,30 290,0 290,40 300,10 300,20 300,30 320,0 320,10 320,20 320,30 320,40 330,0 330,20 330,30 340,10 340,20 340,40 360,0 360,10 360,20 360,30 360,40 370,40 380,40 400,0 400,10 400,20 400,30 400,40 410,0 410,40 420,10 420,20 420,30 480,0 480,10 480,20 480,40 490,0 490,20 490,40 500,0 500,10 500,20 500,30 500,40
```

And here it is turned into an image:

[image]

It could probably be golfed a bit more here and there, but the main gain would come from a smarter font encoding.

I can explain the code in more detail if anyone asks.

Comment: I'm sorry to give bad news but it shows 90º rotated clock-wise and horizontally inverted. Other than that, it looks awesome

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yeah, I posted a comment earlier on the question above. His rules tell to output `x,y`, but his demo code reads the numbers as `y,x`. I chose to go with the rules and flipped `cp[0]` and `cp[1]` to take the screenshot. But in case it turns out to be `y,x`, I'll just have to flip one symbol in my code.

Comment: I made an "improved" version of the code and it prints perfectly using the example he gave. MAYBE you should do like in the example. And add a comment to the code, regarding this issue. This is my opinion, you are free to go ahead and do what you want. The only thing is that he is using it in Javascript and the result looks perfect except for that tiny difference I told in the last comment. But other than that, you did a nice work.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (E6) 274

(261 function + 13 console output)

Not so short, *but* any font, any size, any character

```
F=(m,f="50",F="Georgia")=>{d=1024;e=document.createElement("canvas");c=e.getContext("2d");e.height=e.width=d;c.font=f+"px "+F;c.fillText(m,0,f);
i=c.getImageData(0,0,d,d).data;q='';for(p=d*d*4;p;p-=4)i[p-1]&&(q+=(p>>12)+'0,'+((p>>2)&(d-1))+'0 ');return q.trim()}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
function F(m, f="50", F="Georgia") {
  d = 1024   
  e = document.createElement("canvas")
  c = e.getContext("2d")
  e.height = e.width=d
  c.font = f + "px " + F
  c.fillText(m,0,f);
  i = c.getImageData(0,0,d,d).data;
  q=''
  for (p = d*d*4; p; p-=4)
    i[p-1] && (q += (p >> 12)+'0,'+((p>>2) & (d-1))+'0 ');
  return q.trim()
}
```

**Usage**

`console.log(F('HELLO WORLD'))`

`console.log(F('Bonjour, monde',30,'Garamond'))`